# Trying to click an <a> link using JQuery but the tag doesn't have any descriptors

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I would like to click on a link on the website http://www.furaffinity.net/view/33063264/ but the `<a>` element has no description factors so, I have no idea how to find it properly. This may be set as a duplicate of my other question but, this will be more descriptive and better organized.
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/60obtL8v/

I have tried using JQuery to locate the element with no luck. I don't know if my code was wrong or not. I've deleted the code and would've liked to find it again but, I couldn't.

My JS script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Say "Very Nice!"
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Say "Very Nice" on a post by clicking the button.
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.furaffinity.net/view/*
// @match        http://www.furaffinity.net/view/*
// @match        www.furaffinity.net/view/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
    function addButton(text, onclick, cssObj) {
        cssObj = cssObj || {position: 'absolute', bottom: '15%', left:'4%', 'z-index': 3}
        let button = document.createElement('button'), btnStyle = button.style
        document.body.appendChild(button)
        button.innerHTML = text
        button.onclick = onclick
        Object.keys(cssObj).forEach(key => btnStyle[key] = cssObj[key])
        return button
    }

(function(){
    'use strict'

  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    addButton('Very Nice!', gfg_Run)
    })

      var el_down = document.getElementById("JSMessage");
        var inputF = document.getElementById("JSMessage");
    var yeet = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
    var inputH = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
     function gfg_Run() {
            inputF.value = "Very Nice!";
            el_down.innerHTML =
                   "Value = " + "'" + inputF.value + "'";
         yeet[0].click();
                inputH.click();
          }
}())
```

My expected results are that I could click on the `<a>` tag by clicking on a button elsewhere on the page. I have no idea how i would even locate the element, as it is under a `<div>` and a `<b>` element.

An example of what the HTML of the page looks like:

```html
<div class="alt1 actions aligncenter" style="margin-top: 8px;">

  This is what i would like to click right here. --->
  <b><a href="/fav/33151503/?key=37dfe6a83f38f48790a6551921ddb13850e2c6a0">+Add to Favorites</a></b> |
  <b><a href="//d.facdn.net/art/legacy2988/stories/1569252982/1569252982.legacy2988_i’m_not_sure_atm.txt">Download</a></b> |
  <b><a href="/full/33151503/">Full View</a></b> | <b><a href="/newpm/legacy2988/">Send note</a></b>


  <div>Submission &copy; 2019 Legacy2988</div>
</div>
```

Hopefully, I structured this question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks like pure JS but in jQuery you can use the attribute selector to select the href and perform the action:

```
jQuery('a[@href*=/fav/33151503/?key=37dfe6a83f38f48790a6551921ddb13850e2c6a0]');
```

OR

```
$('a[@href*=/fav/33151503/?key=37dfe6a83f38f48790a6551921ddb13850e2c6a0]');
```

Comment: This seems to work but, only on this certain page. Every post has a different "favourite ID" so would 
```jQuery('a[@href*=/fav/*]');``` 
be possible?